# Getting different default java versions for different users in linux

Tags: rhel, users, java, version

how to set different versions of java to different users in Linux
for example if we login as root then the default java version must be jre-1.8.141 and if we login as the normal user say (rob) then the default java version should be jre-1.8.144.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite trivial. Add this to the user .bashrc file

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/javaXYZdir 
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
```

Mind XYZ.

This assumes user shell is bash.